# How to Initialize an abstract class field which is not used by extending sub class

Tags: java, abstract-class

Here is my problem :

I have this abstract class :

```
public abstract class MyService {
    private MyCache myCache;

    protected MyService(MyCache myCache){
        this.myCache = myCache;
    }

    void someMethod(){
        // work with the myCache
    }
}
```

Now I have a sub class as below :

```
public class ServiceA extends MyService {
    
    ServiceA () {  // getting error in this line

    }

    // some fields and implementations.

}
```

If I do this, the error goes :

```
public class ServiceA extends MyService {

    private MyCache myCache;
    
    ServiceA (MyCache myCache) {  // getting error in this line
        super(myCache);
    }

    // some fields and implementations.
}
```

My requirement is I dont need the MyCache field to be available to **ServiceA** or **ServiceB**. However while creating the constructor for **ServiceA** or **ServiceB** the compiler is throwing error that I need to insert **super();** But I dont need this field to be available to the sub classes because I dont use it there. What I can do to achieve that.

Comment: Nothing. With that constellation you have to call `super(someCache)`. You might be able to call `super(null)`, but I bet that you will get a NPE then in the method `someMethod`. The real solution is to think about a better design. If `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` do not need the cache, why are they subclasses of `MyService`?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose ; As of now I dont see any requirement to use myCache in the sub classes. So  I thought if its a bad design the way I am implementing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need it to be available to the subclasses, but you *do* need it to be *there* for the subclasses, because it's used in `someMethod`.  So you must pass it into `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` constructors even so.

If that *isn't* the case -- if `someMethod` is overridden, for example -- then what you have is a bad design, in which maybe `MyService` *shouldn't* implement `someMethod`.

Comment: So if I pass the myCache field from the sub class, it wont be considered as a bad design right ?

Comment: As long as it's still used in some actual behavior of the class.  It really depends on `someMethod` and whether it's still used in `ServiceA`.

Comment: `someMethod` is being used in `ServiceA`.  I am passing the `myCache` object to the abstract class via the `someMethod()` method parameter and hence removed the abstract class field `myCache` and its explicit constructor. That should be fine right ?

Comment: It...sounds okay, but it's not super clear what you mean.